# Using SMOTE filter for weka API in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, weka

I am attempting to use the SMOTE filter in my java file. I am using Eclipse and have added weka.jar to the build path. However, weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE is not in the weka.jar file so it is not recognized. I understand there is a separate SMOTE.jar file, which I have downloaded, but I am unsure of how to include it in Eclipse so that it recognizes "weka.filter.supervised.instance.SMOTE". I have tried including both jar files in the classpath, but that is giving me greater issues. Here is my Eclipse page right now for reference:

eclipse photo:

[image]

Comment: Open the SMOTE jar, take out the Smote class and add just that to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse project you should see JRE System Library which is missing in the provided picture also `System` class is underlined.
You should add it in project libraries as well as WEKA jar files.